# select box population function not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am new to the world of web dev and so far, for the most part, everything has been peaches and cream and daffodils and teddy bears. Having a blast making a pretty form in Google Chrome.

The thing is, most of the people in the company I work for will be filling this form out via `IE-9`.

All of my `select` elements are broken in `IE-9`. The values work and the `option`s are created, but no text shows up.

This is my population function:

```
function fill_select(select, options)
{
    for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) 
    {
      var opt= options[i];
      var el= document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent= opt;
      el.value= opt;
      select.add(el);
    }
}
```

I could fiddle around with other ways to do it, like modifying `innerHTML`, but I want to know why it doesn't work in `IE-9`, so I can avoid these mistakes in the future.

FYI

- neither `select.add` or `select.appendChild` work.
- neither `el.textContent` or `el.text` work.

Comment: I think you want to just use `.text` instead of `.textContent` as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070383/fixed-why-is-my-dynamic-select-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: `.text` is what I had originally, but I changed it to `.textContent`, hoping that was the issue. Neither of them work.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the option before you set the text and value? See the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @GreeKatrina AH! the answer was the combination of both of your comments. I had to change `el.textContent` to `el.text` and also move `select.add` above `el.text`. Please create an answer outlining this and I will accept it. Thank you ( ͡ᵔ ͜ʖ ͡ᵔ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is:

- Add the option
- THEN add the text and value
- And finally, use `.text`

```
select.add(el);
el.text = opt;
el.value = opt;
```

Glad that worked for you! =)